# youtube-dl won't work on Linux Mint 18.3 64 bit but does on Fedora 34

Tags: firefox, youtube

youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GnvfNx2TGFs
[youtube] GnvfNx2TGFs: Downloading webpage
[youtube] GnvfNx2TGFs: Downloading video info webpage
WARNING: unable to download video info webpage: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
WARNING: unable to download video info webpage: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
WARNING: unable to download video info webpage: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
WARNING: unable to download video info webpage: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
ERROR: GnvfNx2TGFs: YouTube said: Unable to extract video data

Comment: Your Mint is really old (and off-topic here).   It's working for me in Ubuntu (or was day-before-yesterday being the last time I used it)...  FYI: Even the Ubuntu your Mint is based on is out of *standard* level support so doesn't get upgrades and security patches..  You should monitor your software & use a supported system.    https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/

Comment: loader.to is a web interface for this purpose as an alternative

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @HuHa try updating using pip, see instructions in main website [here](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html).